# arithmetic average of an array with range -5 to 5 in c

Tags: c, arrays, math

I want to generate the arithmetic average from an array, but only with values from a certain range (here from -5 to 5)

Is this code ok?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n, i;
float num[100], sum = 0.0, average;

printf("Enter the numbers of elements: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

while (n > 10 || n <= 0)
{
    printf("Error! number should in range of (1 to 10).\n");
    printf("Enter the number again: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d. Enter number: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    if( num[i]< 5 && num[i]>-5){
sum+= num[i];

}

average = sum / n;
printf("Average = %.2f", average);

return 0;
```

edit : I am sorry I must have missed copying the whole code in th eheat of the moment.

It is a simple question I know bu I cannot seem to get it to work. Maybe the lack of sleep is making me go insane

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: What is the value of `n`? How do you initialize `sum`? For some specified input, what is the expected result, and what is the actual result? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If it works, it is ok. If it doesn't, then show us the whole code and tell us your errors.

Comment: *"Is this code ok?"* -- No. `n` does not get updated, there's no check for array with no elements in range, ...

Comment: @Badda *It it works, it is okay* -- No!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Well in this particular case if this part of the code is working with the rest, then we only can suppose it is ok. Please don't quote me adding extra "ay" after my "ok" it hurts my feelings

Comment: Please show an example of input, actual output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

And it's poorly formatted and that's the reason why you don't see why it's wrong:

Your poorly formatted code:

```
...

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d. Enter number: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    if( num[i]< 5 && num[i]>-5){
sum+= num[i];

}     // it looks as if the for loop end here, but it doesn't

average = sum / n;
printf("Average = %.2f", average);

return 0;
}     // the for loop actually ends here
```

The same code formatted correctly:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  printf("%d. Enter number: ", i + 1);
  scanf("%f", &num[i]);

  if (num[i]< 5 && num[i]>-5) {
    sum += num[i];
  }

  average = sum / n;
  printf("Average = %.2f", average);

  return 0;
}                  // <<< the for loop ends here
```

Correct code (look at the comments for an explanation):

```
...
int nbofnumbers = 0;   // number of numbers in the interval [-5,5]

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  printf("%d. Enter number: ", i + 1);
  scanf("%f", &num[i]);

  if (num[i]< 5 && num[i]>-5) {
    nbofnumbers++;
    sum += num[i];
  }
}                              // for loop must end here

average = sum / nbofnumbers;   // we divide by the number of numbers
                               // in the interval [-5,5], not by n
printf("Average = %.2f", average);

return 0;
...
```